# How to use Filter Option in QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtableview, qtablewidget

I am using QTableWidget to display csv data. When I enter a keyword, I want filter action to be performed similar to excel. It should effect all the rows and columns.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
from PyQt4.QtCore import QString

from PyQt4.QtGui import * 
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

import MySQLdb
import os
import time
import sys
import hashlib
import getpass
import webbrowser
import csv

filter_class = uic.loadUiType("filter.ui")[0]

class Filter_window(QtGui.QWidget, filter_class):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        #self.selectall.clicked.connect(self.selectall_application)
        #self.filnext.clicked.connect(self.filnext_application)

         self.loadAll()


    def loadAll(self):

        with open("Rts.csv", "rb") as inpfil:

            reader = csv.reader(inpfil, delimiter = ',')
            csheader = reader.next()
            ncol = len(csheader)
            data = list(reader)
            row_count = len(data)

            self.filterall.setRowCount(row_count)
            self.filterall.setColumnCount(ncol)
            self.filterall.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QString('%s' % ', '.join(map(str, csheader))).split(","))

            for ii in range(0, row_count):
                print data[ii]

                mainins = data[ii]
                print mainins


                for var in range(0,ncol):                                                  
                    print mainins[var], "\n"
                    self.filterall.setItem(ii, var, QTableWidgetItem(mainins[var]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    filterwin = Filter_window()
    filterwin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

filterall is object name fot QTableWidget

.ui code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>allCases</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="allCases">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>597</width>
    <height>466</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>All Cases</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
   <item row="3" column="0" colspan="4">
    <widget class="Line" name="line">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="4" column="3">
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="filnext">
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <pointsize>12</pointsize>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Next</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="4" column="2">
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="selectall">
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <pointsize>12</pointsize>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Select All</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="0" column="1">
    <widget class="QLineEdit" name="filterEdit">
     <property name="toolTip">
      <string/>
     </property>
     <property name="statusTip">
      <string/>
     </property>
     <property name="placeholderText">
      <string>Enter keyword to search</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="0" column="2">
    <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
      <size>
       <width>40</width>
       <height>20</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </spacer>
   </item>
   <item row="1" column="0" colspan="4">
    <widget class="QTableWidget" name="filterall"/>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Could you also show us the content of filter.ui?

Comment: How do you want the filter to work?

Comment: @eyllanesc If i filter, it must effect all rows. Something like in excel. lets suppose there are 12 columns. On the header if i click, it must display all the possible texts and after selecting, it must show only those. And also, if someone types something in search bar, it must search in 3,4,5,6 columns ...

Comment: Would the filtering be per column or all columns?

Comment: option must be for a specific column and result must be updated in all the columns. in column 3, there is a word "YES". When i select that, it must show all the rows that contain "YES" in column 3. so final output will be like, a row with column 0-12 will be displayed IF 3rd column is "YES". ALSO SEARCH MUST BE POSSIBLE FOR COLUMN 3

Comment: @eyllanesc Any Solution ?

Comment: Try my solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is filtered by clicking on the header of each column, it will show the possible values, and checking them will filter.

Complete code:

```
import csv
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore

from PyQt4 import QtGui


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.filterall = QtGui.QTableWidget(self)
        self.filterall.setColumnCount(0)
        self.filterall.setRowCount(0)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.filterall)

        self.loadAll()
        self.horizontalHeader = self.filterall.horizontalHeader()
        self.horizontalHeader.sectionClicked.connect(self.on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked)
        self.keywords = dict([(i, []) for i in range(self.filterall.columnCount())])
        self.checkBoxs = []
        self.col = None

    def slotSelect(self, state):

        for checkbox in self.checkBoxs:
            checkbox.setChecked(QtCore.Qt.Checked == state)

    def on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked(self, index):
        # self.clearFilter()
        self.menu = QtGui.QMenu(self)
        self.col = index

        data_unique = []

        self.checkBoxs = []

        checkBox = QtGui.QCheckBox("Select all", self.menu)
        checkableAction = QtGui.QWidgetAction(self.menu)
        checkableAction.setDefaultWidget(checkBox)
        self.menu.addAction(checkableAction)
        checkBox.setChecked(True)
        checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.slotSelect)

        for i in range(self.filterall.rowCount()):
            if not self.filterall.isRowHidden(i):
                item = self.filterall.item(i, index)
                if item.text() not in data_unique:
                    data_unique.append(item.text())
                    checkBox = QtGui.QCheckBox(item.text(), self.menu)
                    checkBox.setChecked(True)
                    checkableAction = QtGui.QWidgetAction(self.menu)
                    checkableAction.setDefaultWidget(checkBox)
                    self.menu.addAction(checkableAction)
                    self.checkBoxs.append(checkBox)

        btn = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel,
                                     QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self.menu)
        btn.accepted.connect(self.menuClose)
        btn.rejected.connect(self.menu.close)
        checkableAction = QtGui.QWidgetAction(self.menu)
        checkableAction.setDefaultWidget(btn)
        self.menu.addAction(checkableAction)

        headerPos = self.filterall.mapToGlobal(self.horizontalHeader.pos())

        posY = headerPos.y() + self.horizontalHeader.height()
        posX = headerPos.x() + self.horizontalHeader.sectionPosition(index)
        self.menu.exec_(QtCore.QPoint(posX, posY))

    def menuClose(self):
        self.keywords[self.col] = []
        for element in self.checkBoxs:
            if element.isChecked():
                self.keywords[self.col].append(element.text())
        self.filterdata()
        self.menu.close()

    def loadAll(self):
        with open("Rts.csv", "rb") as inpfil:
            reader = csv.reader(inpfil, delimiter=',')
            csheader = reader.next()
            ncol = len(csheader)
            data = list(reader)
            row_count = len(data)

            self.filterall.setRowCount(row_count)
            self.filterall.setColumnCount(ncol)
            self.filterall.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QtCore.QString('%s' % ', '.join(map(str, csheader))).split(","))

            for ii in range(0, row_count):
                mainins = data[ii]
                for var in range(0, ncol):
                    self.filterall.setItem(ii, var, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(mainins[var]))

    def clearFilter(self):
        for i in range(self.filterall.rowCount()):
            self.filterall.setRowHidden(i, False)

    def filterdata(self):

        columnsShow = dict([(i, True) for i in range(self.filterall.rowCount())])

        for i in range(self.filterall.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.filterall.columnCount()):
                item = self.filterall.item(i, j)
                if self.keywords[j]:
                    if item.text() not in self.keywords[j]:
                        columnsShow[i] = False
        for key, value in columnsShow.iteritems():
            self.filterall.setRowHidden(key, not value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You So much... It is working awesome and fine as i expected. But there is a problem. I already have a GUI made in QtDesigner. Will it create any problem if i add this class there ?

Comment: @PradyumnaCheerala 
I upload a project to github with your code that you have shown and my project in a few hours.

Comment: @PradyumnaCheerala complete code: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/FilterTable

Comment: Can we write the filtered table values into csv file ? If so, how can we ?

Comment: I was trying to print the data.. I am getting it in True False state. So I cant write that into csv. How to retrieve the data that is being displayed? So that i can save it in csv file ?

Comment: What are you sending to print?

Comment: after filtering, there are few columns that are being displayed in QTableWidget. I want those filtered values to be written into csv file.

Comment: That's simple, I think you can try. :P

Comment: Yaa I am trying .... but it is displaying true false values... OK .. lemme check and come back to you. Or could you please give a hint ?

Comment: can you say where can i message u ?

Comment: I cant post the information here. Its too long to post it here. if you want me to gmail you i will

Comment: Upload it to github and share it

Comment: https://github.com/Pradyumna007/testfilter code is here .... and sorry for late reply .... could you please check on this ?

Comment: see this: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/Save2CSV

Comment: Hi, That worked fine. Thanks. Can you suggest me how to do this action if I am trying to take a keyword from the user and try filtering it. I tried modifying your code little bit but didnt work. Could you please suggest how to proceed further?

https://github.com/Pradyumna007/anothertest